# Hide column in EPPlus not working

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to hide a column in excel using EPPlus nuget package and its not working (It didn't hide the column)

this is what I have found that is supposed to do the trick. Maybe there is a bug ?

```
worksheet.Column(1).Hidden = true;
```

I am using version 4.5.2.1

Project URL https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (inside the question, people generally won't click external links).

Comment: my screen went purple! na not really. It doesn't hide the column.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was calling

```
worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
```

after

```
worksheet.Column(1).Hidden = true;
```

AutoFitColumns was removing the hide effect.

Answer (score 3):

[I'm pretty sure it's a bug.](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/568)

As of this writing (2019-10-24), there's code in `AutoFitColumns` that tries to avoid doing auto-fit for hidden columns, but it's executed after a helper method (`SetMinWidth`) is invoked that goes through all the columns setting a minimum width, and the `Width` setter includes the side effect of setting `_hidden` to `false` if the width is non-zero, which it is when using the zero-parameter overload of `AutoFitColumns`.

If you use the 1- or 2-parameter overloads of `AutoFitColumns` to pass in a minimum width of zero, the columns will remain hidden, but your empty columns will be zero-width, so it's not really a workaround.

Here's an extension method that I'm using as a workaround, for now:

```cs
static void AutoFitColumnsAndRehide(this ExcelRangeBase range)
{
    range.Reset();

    var hiddenColumns = range
        .Select(cell => cell.Start.Column)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(range.Worksheet.Column)
        .Where(column => column.Hidden)
        .ToList();

    range.AutoFitColumns();

    foreach (var column in hiddenColumns)
    {
        column.Hidden = true;
    }
}
```

This can obviously be adjusted for the 1- and 2-parameter overloads, as well.

Comment: Thanks for this.  As useful as I find EPPlus, the side-effect driven nature of so many things makes it nearly impossible to parse out why things don't work, and why things must be executed in a specific pattern for some features to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently according to the documentation, you can use `AutoFitColumns(Double MinimumWidth, Double MaximumWidth)`:

> Set the column width from the content of the range. Note: Cells containing formulas are ignored if no calculation is made. Wrapped and merged cells are also ignored. **Hidden columns are left hidden**.

```
    worksheet.Column(1).Hidden = true;
    worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns(8.43,100); // 8.43 = default width of cells
```